# PyQT5 Window not opening

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyqt5, pylance

**When trying to finish my optimization program , the pyQT5 window isnt opening !!. Please Help**
*Here is my code*

*Did i maybe call the window wrong or smth ?*
**ERROR MESSAGE : *QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget* **

=CODE START=

```
import sys
import os
import ctypes
import psutil
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QMessageBox, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from openai import OpenAI
import shutil
import time

# Vars
authors = ["DextolReiniger3000", "", "", ""]
cred_1 = "Powered with AI"
version = 0

user_variable = os.environ.get('USERNAME')

# API KEY
OpenAI.api_key = "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"

# Function to check for admin privileges
def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

class MinecraftOptimizerApp(QWidget):
    console_text = None  # Class-level variable
    option_buttons = []  # Class-level variable

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Create widgets
        self.login_label = QLabel('Enter Password:')
        self.login_entry = QLineEdit()
        self.login_button = QPushButton('Login')
        self.console_text = QTextEdit()  # Initialize console_text here
        self.chat_output = QTextEdit()
        self.input_entry = QLineEdit()
        self.send_button = QPushButton('Send')

        # Set up layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.login_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.login_entry)
        layout.addWidget(self.login_button)
        layout.addWidget(self.console_text)
        layout.addWidget(self.input_entry)
        layout.addWidget(self.chat_output)
        layout.addWidget(self.send_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Set up signals
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.send_button.clicked.connect(self.on_send_click)

        self.setWindowTitle('Minecraft Optimizer')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

    def login(self):
        entered_pass = self.login_entry.text()

        if entered_pass == "testpass":
            MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Password is Correct! Continuing in 3 seconds...")
            QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.switch_to_chat)
        elif entered_pass == "developerpass":
            MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Logging into developer session...")
            dev_password, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Developer Password', 'Enter Developer Password:')
            if ok and dev_password == "dextolreiniger3000testbase":
                MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Logging in as 'DextolReiniger3000 [ADMINISTRATOR]'")
                QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.switch_to_chat)
            else:
                MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Developer Password is incorrect. Please try again.")
        else:
            MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("User Password is incorrect. Please try again.")

    def switch_to_chat(self):
        self.login_label.hide()
        self.login_entry.hide()
        self.login_button.hide()

        self.input_entry.show()
        self.chat_output.show()
        self.send_button.show()

    def on_send_click(self):
        user_input = self.input_entry.text()
        if user_input.lower() == "exit":
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'ChatGPT', 'Exiting ChatGPT...')
            sys.exit()
        elif user_input.lower() == "pco":
            self.chat_output.append("")  # Dummy newline to separate options from previous text
            for button in MinecraftOptimizerApp.option_buttons:
                button.show()
        else:
            response = self.chat_with_gpt(user_input)
            self.chat_output.append(response)

    def chat_with_gpt(self, user_input):
        client = OpenAI()
        response_text = ""

        stream = client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
            messages=[{"role": "user", "content": user_input}],
            stream=True,
        )

        for chunk in stream:
            response_text += chunk.choices[0].delta.content

        return response_text

# Additional functions (outside the class)
def run_antivirus_scan():
    if is_admin():
        MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Running antivirus scan...")
        try:
            subprocess.run(['"%ProgramFiles%\\Windows Defender\\MpCmdRun.exe"', '-Scan', '-ScanType', '3'], check=True)
            MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Antivirus scan completed successfully.")
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append(f"Error running antivirus scan: {e}")
        MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Antivirus scan finished.")
    else:
        MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Insufficient privileges to run antivirus scan.")

def update_software():
    MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Updating software...")
    try:
        subprocess.run(['pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'], check=True)
        MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Python packages updated successfully.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append(f"Error updating Python packages: {e}")
    MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Software update completed.")

def perform_disk_cleanup():
    if is_admin():
        MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Cleaning up disk space...")
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join('C:\\Users', user_variable, 'AppData\\Local\\Temp'))
            MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Disk cleanup completed.")
        except Exception as e:
            MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append(f"Error during disk cleanup: {e}")
    else:
        MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Insufficient privileges to perform disk cleanup.")

def optimize_system_performance():
    MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("Optimizing system performance...")
    MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("System Information:")
    MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append(f"CPU Usage: {psutil.cpu_percent()}%")
    MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append(f"Memory Usage: {psutil.virtual_memory().percent}%")
    close_unnecessary_processes()
    delete_large_files()
    MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append("System performance optimized successfully.")

def close_unnecessary_processes():
    unnecessary_processes = ["msedge.exe", "msteams.exe"]
    for process_name in unnecessary_processes:
        try:
            for process in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
                if process.info['name'] == process_name:
                    MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append(f"Closing {process_name} (PID: {process.info['pid']})")
                    process.terminate()
        except Exception as e:
            MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append(f"Error closing process {process_name}: {e}")

def delete_large_files():
    target_path = os.path.join('C:\\Users', user_variable, 'Downloads')
    threshold_size = 100
    try:
        MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append(f"Searching for large files in {target_path}...")
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target_path):
            for file in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path) / (1024 * 1024)
                if file_size > threshold_size:
                    MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append(f"Deleting large file: {file_path} (Size: {file_size:.2f} MB)")
                    os.remove(file_path)
    except Exception as e:
        MinecraftOptimizerApp.console_text.append(f"Error deleting large files: {e}")

# Create buttons for optimization options
MinecraftOptimizerApp.option_buttons = [
    QPushButton('Clean up disk space'),
    QPushButton('Optimize system performance'),
    QPushButton('Update software'),
    QPushButton('Run antivirus scan'),
    QPushButton('Exit'),
    QPushButton('Return to ChatGPT')
]

# Connect each button to its corresponding function
MinecraftOptimizerApp.option_buttons[0].clicked.connect(perform_disk_cleanup)
MinecraftOptimizerApp.option_buttons[1].clicked.connect(optimize_system_performance)
MinecraftOptimizerApp.option_buttons[2].clicked.connect(update_software)
MinecraftOptimizerApp.option_buttons[3].clicked.connect(run_antivirus_scan)
MinecraftOptimizerApp.option_buttons[4].clicked.connect(sys.exit)
MinecraftOptimizerApp.option_buttons[5].clicked.connect(lambda: MinecraftOptimizerApp.option_buttons[5].hide())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MinecraftOptimizerApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i was expecting the generated pyQT window to open but it didnt work :(

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The error tells exactly where the problem is: among other things, you're trying to create widgets (specifically, the buttons) before a QApplication instance is created. Move the creation of the buttons elsewhere, possibly within the class constructor. In any case, you should be much more careful about creating and using attributes, especially when it's clear that they should be instance members, as it's quite pointless to make the buttons and text edit as class members.